# How to get rid of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, angularjs-controller

When i try to run below code i got error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a
   at Object.parse (native)
   at pc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:14:219)
   at Yb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:76:201)

This is my index.html file where i post data to the server via $http post method when form is submit and try to get responce from server via $http get method

### index.html

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" ng-submit="employeeLogin(my)">
    <input type="email" ng-model="my.employeeEmail">
    <input type="password" ng-model="my.employeePassword">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('validateCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
        $scope.employeeLogin = function(my) {
            var formData = {
                "employeeEmail": $scope.my.employeeEmail,
                "employeePassword": $scope.my.employeePassword
            }
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/TheSanshaWorld/sfcms/employeeLogin", formData).success(function(data) {
                $http.get('http://localhost:8080/TheSanshaWorld/sfcms/employeeLogin').success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data); //Uncaught Exception E
                    $scope.stores = data;
                });
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

This is my controller and here i post employee data to the server and return the role of employee and want to store in role variable. here i got the response from the server and got the data but when this data is passed to the client side we got Uncaught Exception a error:

### EmployeeLoginController.java

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping({"/sfcms/**"})
    public class EmployeeLoginController {
      @Autowired
      EmployeeLoginService employeeloginservice;
      @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      public @ResponseBody String employeeLogin(@RequestBody EmployeeDetailDto employeeDetail){
    String role= employeeloginservice.employeeLogin(employeeDetail.getEmployeeEmail() , employeeDetail.getEmployeePassword());
    return role;
    }
```

Comment: Most likely you return malformed JSON response, what will you get if you do `console.log(data)` in both of $http requests?

Comment: i got error: Unexpected token E  at Object.parse (native)

Comment: And if you open developer tools in your browser, check network tab and the response for your requests

Comment: its check email id in db and return its name ( ex:admin or if its not matching return not matching value)

Comment: can you add EXACT body of the response you get for accessing both of the URLS from your code?

Comment: Sir, i got response like "Your email id and password does not match". that things i saw in network tab

Comment: That's not a json response. Also why are you making nested request to the same url? Doesn't make sense to post and inside that post make a get to same api endpoint

Comment: Sir, its necessary to get response in json format ? because of i need only value not key

Comment: The code in the spring controller is not enough, can you also put the 'GET' handler for the '/employeeLogin'. 
Also i do not get why do you need to post and then a get.

Comment: sir , actually i try with 
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/TheSanshaWorld/sfcms/employeeLogin", formData).success(function(data) {
$scope.data = data;
});
but this will return error also,

Comment: If you just need text then you need to configure `responseType: 'text'` for the $http request